# Draw rotated rectangle

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm new to C# and .net, just trying to work out how to do something that I thought would be relatively simple. 
I'm creating a bitmap to be later saved as an image to disk, part of it I want to draw a rectangle shape. 
I can do this, however I'm looking for a simple way to do this on an angle. I need to be able to specify an angle to draw the rectangle at, I also need to be able to to specify the rotation point (I need to rotate around the top left hand point of the rectangle).

How is this usually achieved with  c#/.net, is there something built in for this sort of thing that I haven't found ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class supports setting transforms that will let you scale, shear, rotate, etc. See [Coordinate Systems and Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zxbwxch.aspx).

You can find an example at [Using a matrix to rotate rectangles individually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10210134/56778).

Comment: Thanks ! The matrices was the missing link.