# Drawing a rectangle with a certain angle of degree

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, rectangles, drawrectangle

I'm using Windows visual studio 2015 winforms to draw rectangles on a panel.
I get my information from a list of objects(bricks). I just check the rotation for each brick:

My brick holds the following information:

```
    string ID;
    PointF MiddlePoint;
    float Length;
    float Height;
    float Rotation;
```

Creating the rectangle with a 90/270 angle of degree.

```
if (a_BrickList[i].Rotation == 90 || a_BrickList[i].Rotation == 270)
{
      UpperLeftPoint.X = Xorigin + (a_BrickList[i].MiddlePoint.X - (a_BrickList[i].Length / 2) + panelOffset) * scale;
      UpperLeftPoint.Y = Yorigin - (a_BrickList[i].MiddlePoint.Y + (a_BrickList[i].Height / 2) + panelOffset) * scale;
      rect = new RectangleF(UpperLeftPoint.X, UpperLeftPoint.Y, Length, Height);
      GlueRectangles[i] = rect;
}
```

I've added another if statement:

```
 if (a_BrickList[i].Rotation != 0 && a_BrickList[i].Rotation != 180 &&
     a_BrickList[i].Rotation != 90 && a_BrickList[i].Rotation != 270)
```

In this one I want to draw a rectangle on a certain angle of degree. But I can't really find anything about the `rectangle` with `rotate` or `angle`.

So is there a way to draw a rectangle with a certain angle of degree?

Or can I only solve this by calculating the 4 points of my rectangle and draw lines between them?

Comment: whick drawing framework are you using?

Comment: Are you using GDI+? It's really not clear.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015

Comment: Rectangle by definition should has all the angles to be 90 degrees. So if you need it to has another angles - it is parallelogramm, draw it munually line by line.

Comment: Do you mean the angle between one edge and the imaginary line between two vertices? (e.g. BAC for a rectangle with vertices ABCD)?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the rectangle or to draw a rhomboid?

Comment: Vague question, vague answers... Do you perhaps mean to rotate a rectangle at a specified angle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402311/draw-rotated-rectangle

Comment: All rectangles have 4 angles, each 90 degrees ^_^

Comment: I'd prefer `DrawPolygon` over separate lines, like if you might later decide to fill it and use the same input parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the drawing environment you're using.

For example, if you use HTML5 canvas, you could rotate the canvas, draw the rectangle and then return the canvas to the original position, obtaining the "rotated" rectangle.

You should check your environment documentation for further info or give more info in the question so we can help you.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Bardo yes `RotateTransform` in winforms is the same concept as rotating the canvas