# Is it possible to rotate a drawing half-way its definition?

Tags: c#, drawing, rotatetransform

I'm doing some draws that are repetitive, and each of them gives lot of work.
What i need to do is rotate the drawing half-way its definition, something like this:

```
 using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            //define area do pictureBox e preenche a branco
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(0, 0, 520, 520);
            g.FillRectangle(brush, area);

           //rotate
           g.RotateTransform(some angle, some reference point)

           //draw some more lines on the top of the rotated previous ones.
}
```

I tried using `g.RotateTransform(90)` as there is that function in Winforms, but it didn't change anything. Why??

Any tip?

Edit: if it helps, i only need to rotate fixed angles, 180º

Comment: See [Using a matrix to rotate rectangles individually](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10210639/719186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RotateTransform` certainly does change the **subsequent** drawing.

Note that you usually need a `TranslateTransform` before to set the rotation point. But it '*it didn't change anything*' is certainly wrong. Try again! And yes you can rotate (or scale  or move) at any point and move/turn it back or completely reset the `Graphics` object.

And yes, learning about `Matrix` and `MultiplyTransform` is also very helpful..

**But:** You need to understand the `Graphics` object does not **contain** any graphic, a common misconception! It is the tool which **does** the drawing on a `Bitmap`, most often the surface of a `Control`. So the rotation **will** happen but only for the things you draw **after**:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(25, 25, 25, 25);

    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(25, 25);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, rect);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        rect.Inflate(2, 2);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(5, 2);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(2.5f);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rect);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
use these references:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I made windows application and put on form1 picturebox then this is the code in form_load:

```
       //Load an image in from a file
       Bitmap pImage = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Image.bmp", true);

       //Set our picture box to that image
       pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)pImage.Clone();

       //Store our old image so we can delete it
       Image oldImage = pictureBox1.Image;

       //Pass in our original image and return a new image rotated 35 degrees right
       pictureBox1.Image = RotateImage(pImage, 270);
       if (oldImage != null)
       {
           oldImage.Dispose();
       }
```

Then make static function with parameters of image and rotation angle return the rotated image and call it from form_load as mentioned before :

```
            if (image == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
        }
        else
        {
            //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
            Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

            rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);


            //move rotation point to center of image
            g.TranslateTransform((float)image.Width / 2, (float)image.Height / 2);

            //rotate
            g.RotateTransform(angle);

            //move image back
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)image.Width / 2, -(float)image.Height / 2);

            //draw passed in image onto graphics object
            g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));

            return rotatedBmp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use directly the code in form_load by using ready RotateFlipType (Enumeration type) but this with fixed angles like 90,270,.... but the previous method you can use any integer values to rotate the image :

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load an image in from a file
       Bitmap pImage = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Image.bmp", true);
       pImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
       pictureBox1.Image = pImage;
    }
```