# Rotate a individual rectangle and ALL its contents

Tags: c#, drawing, rotatetransform

I'm using the method posted here 
[Using a matrix to rotate rectangles individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210134/using-a-matrix-to-rotate-rectangles-individually)

(I hope this is not a repost, if it is maybe i'm doing something wrong)

I'm using the perfectly defined RotateRectangle method as follows

```
 public void RotateRectangle(Graphics g, Rectangle r, float angle)
    {
        using (Matrix m = new Matrix())
        {
            m.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(r.Left + (r.Width / 2),
                                      r.Top + (r.Height / 2)));
            g.Transform = m;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
            g.ResetTransform();
        }
    }
```

And then on my drawing i create a label, and a rectangle outside of it

```
g.DrawString("e/10", fnt2, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (int)(ecobdesenho / 10) / 2 + esp - 15, esp - 25); //15 para tras, 15 para cima

            Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle((int)(ecobdesenho / 10) / 2 + esp - 15, esp - 25, 25, 12);


            RotateRectangle(g, r1, 40);
```

[image]

(Notice the rectangle in top left corner)
Am I missing something? Or should I go eat bananas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RotateRectangle` is not rotating a rectangle of canvas; it's *drawing* a rotated rectangle.

Everything that's drawn between setting the `Transform` and the `ResetTransform` will be drawn rotated.

Therefore, if you want the `DrawString` to be rotated, you need to put it after you set the Transform, and before you reset it.

```
using (Matrix m = new Matrix())
{
    m.RotateAt(angle, new PointF(r.Left + (r.Width / 2),
                              r.Top + (r.Height / 2)));
    g.Transform = m;
    g.DrawString("e/10", fnt2, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (int)(ecobdesenho / 10) / 2 + esp - 15, esp - 25); //15 para tras, 15 para cima
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
    g.ResetTransform();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but besides the rotation i have to do a translatetransform, how can i combine both? The ideal would be to first rotate, then translate, but it doesnt work because i believe the g.Transform  = m takes up the whole transformation. @Blorgbeard

Comment: You can do `m.TranslateTransform` after you do the rotate transform. Or maybe before. I forget the default matrix operation order.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work, I think that when i set the g.Transform = m, it changes the relative paths, I created a new question regarding this issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803156/translate-rotate-previously-drawn-rectangle-is-this-possible