# Rotate image in picturebox on timer winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a winform with a circle of buttons, forms have between 6-9 buttons. I have an arrow inside a picturebox that I want to rotate around the centre to stop at each button, and only enable the button that the arrow is facing to be enabled. 
[image]

Here is an example of one of the forms.
When the form loads I want the timer to start and rotate to each button without having to click the page.
The image is in a picturebox so i dont want  (RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)/ (RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY) because it only rotates 90 degrees which doesnt work when you have more than 4 buttons.

Comment: This will be _much_ easier if you use WPF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate image in picture box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450764/how-to-rotate-image-in-picture-box) - Note that I am referring to __my__ answer, which roates at arbitrary angles! - The `angle` variable can be used to determine the right `Button`!

Comment: See [Using a matrix to rotate rectangles individually](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10210639/719186)

Comment: it is not a duplicate as I said I don't want to rotate 90 flip, that example uses that, and I have tried the options available on that question, they were also unsuccessful TaW i tried yours which does not work for me as I am using a picture box

Comment: Also my entire project is winforms so WPF isnt an option because it would mean starting over.