# how to rotate my squares to create my demoscene?

Tags: c#, winforms, rotation, shapes

Im new to C# and so I had the idea to create squares which would rotate. So I didin't have a problem to create my squares but I don't know how to begin to rotate them or what am I supposed to do to rotate them. If it's possible I would like an advice on how to rotate or move my shapes.

This is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap Bmp;//we create a bitmap

    SolidBrush Font = new SolidBrush(Color.Black); // background color

    SolidBrush square1 = new SolidBrush(Color.White);//black and white color for our squares
    SolidBrush square2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);


    Timer timer1;


    int angle = 0; 
    int angle1 = 0;
    int angle2 = 0;
    int angle3 = 0;
    int angle4 = 0;
    int angle5 = 0;
    int angle6 = 0;
    int angle7 = 0;
    int angle8 = 0;
    int angle9 = 0;
    int angle10 = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {

        Bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp);// We create graphics of bitmap

        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.FillRectangle(Font, 0, 0, 979, 525);

        g.TranslateTransform((float)this.Width / 2, (float)this.Height / 2);

        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square1, -110, -110, 220, 220);

        g.RotateTransform(angle1);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square2, -100, -100, 200, 200);

        g.RotateTransform(angle2);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square1, -90, -90, 180, 180);

        g.RotateTransform(angle3);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square2, -80, -80, 160, 160 );

        g.RotateTransform(angle4);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square1, -70, -70, 140, 140);

        g.RotateTransform(angle5);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square2, -60, -60, 120, 120);

        g.RotateTransform(angle6);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square1, -50, -50, 100, 100);

        g.RotateTransform(angle7);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square2, -40, -40, 80, 80);

        g.RotateTransform(angle8);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square1, -30, -30, 60, 60);

        g.RotateTransform(angle9);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square2, -20, -20, 40, 40);

        g.RotateTransform(angle10);
        g.RotateTransform(1);
        g.FillRectangle(square1, -10, -10, 20, 20);


        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Bmp;
    } 


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        angle++;
        angle1++;
        angle2++;
        angle3++;
        angle4++;
        angle5++;
        angle6++;
        angle7++;
        angle8++;
        angle9++;
        angle10++;

        Draw();

        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Bmp;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210134/using-a-matrix-to-rotate-rectangles-individually

Comment: @JohnB I get somehow the concept and I tried to add some command lines from the link you sent me to check how they would work  but i needed to add the `using System.Windows.Media` by adding the PresentationCore.dll but  it still does not  recognise the matrix or the transform commands why is that?

Comment: please update you sample code with the changes made

Comment: What `System.Windows.Media`? This is `Winforms`. You need a reference to `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`.

Comment: Ok i managed to do it thanks for your help i have updated my program .